# How to find Directories that updated last day in linux?

Tags: linux, directory, last

I have a problem, like I need to find the directories that got updated yesterday. I tried using `find` command but its listing all the files that got updated in the directories. But I need only the directory names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use -type d in the find string:

```
find /path/to/target -type d -mtime 1
```

Comment: That command will only find dirs with added, deleted or renamed contents, not dirs which had an existing file modified.  Also be wary of `find`'s handling of things like mtime and size - it is not particularly intuitive.  `find -mtime 1` actually finds files modified between 24.0 and 47.999 hours ago. Contrarily, `find -size 2G` finds files between 1.0 and 1.999 GiB.  My favourite is `find -size -1G` which only finds zero-byte files.  But I digress...

Answer (score 10):

To find dirs containing files modified in the last 24 hours:

```
find [dir-to-search] -type f -mtime -1 -exec dirname {} \; | sort --unique
```

Change the `mtime -1` to `mtime -2` to search the last 48 hours, or change it to `mmin -120` to search the last 2 hours

Edit: explanation:

Searches `dir-to-search` (or current dir if not provided) recursively for entries of type `f` (file) which were modified less than (1*24) hours ago.  Execute the `dirname` command for each of these.  This will give one dirname listing for each file, which may result in many duplicates, so pipe the output to `sort` and ask it to extract unique dirnames.

Comment: Sounds like this one should be the accepted answer, because of the shortcomings mentioned in the comment of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287117/249784

Comment: what would be best way to invert this command (e.g. find directories which have not been modified in the last 24 hours)?